# How to use G2Process in Py QuantLib

Tags: quantlib

I'm trying to do MC using `G2Process` object. The example I'm trying to mimic is in this [link](http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/variance-reduction-hull-white-quantlib.html). Below is a code snippet of what I did. Please will someone guide me on why I'm using the interface incorrectly? Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import QuantLib as ql
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz
ql.__version__

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = 0.1
    sigma = 0.2
    b = 0.4
    eta = 0.17
    rho = -0.8
    timestep = 360
    length = 30 # in years
    forward_rate = 0.05
    day_count = ql.Thirty360()
    todays_date = ql.Date(15, 1, 2015)
    ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todays_date

    yield_curve = ql.FlatForward(todays_date, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(forward_rate)), day_count)
    spot_curve_handle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(yield_curve)
    hw_process = ql.HullWhiteProcess(spot_curve_handle, a, sigma)
    rng = ql.GaussianRandomSequenceGenerator(ql.UniformRandomSequenceGenerator(timestep, ql.UniformRandomGenerator(125)))
    seq = ql.GaussianPathGenerator(hw_process, length, timestep, rng, False)
    def generate_paths(num_paths, timestep):
        arr = np.zeros((num_paths, timestep+1))
        for i in range(num_paths):
            sample_path = seq.next()
            path = sample_path.value()
            time = [path.time(j) for j in range(len(path))]
            value = [path[j] for j in range(len(path))]
            arr[i, :] = np.array(value)
        return np.array(time), arr

    num_paths = 128
    time, paths = generate_paths(num_paths, timestep)
    for i in range(num_paths):
        plt.plot(time, paths[i, :], lw=0.8, alpha=0.6)
    plt.title("HW Short Rate Simulation")
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved what I was seeking. The `G2Process` object has method `evolve` to simulate the MC path. A working code is shown below. Any constructive feedback/comments are welcome. Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import QuantLib as ql
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz
ql.__version__

if __name__ == "__main__":

    a = 0.1
    sigma = 0.2
    b = 0.4
    eta = 0.17
    rho = -0.8
    timestep = 360
    length = 30 # in years

    g2_process = ql.G2Process(a, sigma, b, eta, rho)

    num_paths = 200
    grid = ql.TimeGrid(length, timestep)
    rng = ql.GaussianRandomSequenceGenerator(ql.UniformRandomSequenceGenerator(2, ql.UniformRandomGenerator(125)))

    def generate_paths(num_paths, timestep):
        dz = ql.Array(2, 0.0)
        path = np.zeros(shape = (num_paths, timestep+1))
        sample = ql.Array(2, 0.0)
        for i in range(num_paths):
            ir = ql.Array(2, 0.0)
            for j in range(timestep):
                ir = g2_process.evolve(grid[j], ir, grid.dt(j), dz)              
                sample = rng.nextSequence().value()
                dz[0] = sample[0]
                dz[1] = sample[1]
                path[i,j] = np.sum(ir)
        time = np.array([grid[j] for j in range(len(grid))])
        return time, path

    time, paths = generate_paths(num_paths, timestep)
    arr = np.zeros(shape = (num_paths, timestep))
    for i in range(num_paths):
        plt.plot(time, paths[i, :])
    plt.title("G2 Short Rate Simulation")
    plt.show()
```

[image: G2 Short Rate Simulation]

I also checked if the zero coupon bond could be calculated during the MC simulation via `G2` object. Unfortunately, method `discountBond` is not in the available in v1.17; it's available in QuantLib C++. Hopefully, future version will include it. Thanks.